# Reading serial information in Java

Tags: java, android, python

I'm working on porting an Android app that has already been developed in Python. In the Python program, there is a line that I'm trying to fully understand:

```
self.comfd = Serial(...) # from the pySerial API
....
self.buffer  = list(struct.unpack('192H', self.comfd.read(384)))
```

From what I understand, `self.comfd.read(384)` is reading 384 bytes, and the `unpack('192H'` is unpacking 192 unsigned shorts from that data. Is this correct?

Now in Java, I've been able to read the buffer using

```
SerialPort device = SerialPort(file, baud, flags);
InputStream in = device.getInputStream();
```

My question is, now that I have the input stream, how do I create the unsigned shorts like the Python program is doing?

What I've tried (not producing correct values):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[384];
in.read(buffer);
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length / 2; i++) {
    bb.put(buffer[i]);
    bb.put(buffer[i + 1]);
    short val = bb.getShort(0);
    System.out.println(val);
    bb.clear();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

edit: I incorporated Jason C's answer and also I was looping incorrectly. By changing it to

`for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i=i+2)` that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a char (it's a 16-bit unsigned value in Java), e.g.:

```
byte[] buffer = ...;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer); // don't need to put()
int val = (int)bb.getChar(0);
```

Use bb.order() to set big- vs. little-endian.

You can also just pack the 2 bytes into an int (assuming little-endian) without using a ByteBuffer. Byte is signed in Java, so you will have to convert the byte to an unsigned value before shifting, which you can do by temporarily storing it in a short (or an int or anything large enough to hold 0-255):

```
short b0 = (buffer[0] & 255); // trick converts to unsigned
short b1 = (buffer[1] & 255);
int val = b0 | (b1 << 8);

// or just put it all inline:
int val = (buffer[0]&255) | ((buffer[1]&255) << 8);
```

For big-endian data just swap b0 and b1.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated this answer, my previous answer was not the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no unsigned numbers (`char` is 16bit unsigned but it's not a number and math with `char` will always result in implicit casts to `int`)

If you read 2 bytes of unsigned data into a `short` and want to see values in range from 0-65535 (instead of -32768 - 32767) you'll have to use a type that can have values in that range.

In case of 16bit `short` next bigger one is 32bit `int`. The conversion that does the trick is

```
short signed = ...;
int unsigned = signed & 0xFFFF;
```

Assuming `signed` has a value of `0xFFFF` this is what happens:

```
short signed = -1; // FFFF on byte level
```

The expression `signed & 0xFFFF` contains a `short` and an `int`. `0xFFFF` is a literal integer type number which when found in Java source is considered `int`. You could make it `long` by changing it to `0xFFFFL` (you would need that if you want to convert unsigned `int` to `long`).

Since the `&` operator needs both sides in a common type Java will silently convert the smaller one.

```
int stillSigned = (int) signed; // hidden step
```

It will still have the exact same value of -1 since that's what it was before when looking at it unsigned but it is changed on bytelevel to `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Now the bit-manipulation is applied to remove all the added `FF`s

```
int unsigned = stillSigned & 0xFFFF;
```

and you end up with `0x0000FFFF` on byte level and can finally see the value of 65535.

Since you happen to have 16bit values you can use `char` and simply cast it to `int`.

```
char value = ...;
int unsigned = value;
```

But above approach works for any unsigned conversion: `byteValue & 0xFF`, `shortValue & 0xFFFF`, `intValue & 0xFFFFFFFFL`

---

The next thing you should do is not to use a simple `InputStream` to do

```
SerialPort device = SerialPort(file, baud, flags);
InputStream in = device.getInputStream(); 
byte[] buffer = new byte[384];
in.read(buffer);
```

Reason is that [InputStream#read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29) is not guaranteed to read all the bytes you want in your buffer. It returns you the number of bytes it has read or `-1` if the stream is done. Manually writing code that ensures you have a filled buffer is nasty but there is a simple solution: [DataInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html)

```
SerialPort device = SerialPort(file, baud, flags);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(device.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[384];
in.readFully(buffer);
```

`DataInputStream` has very nice functionality that you could use:

```
SerialPort device = SerialPort(file, baud, flags);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(device.getInputStream());
int unsignedShort = in.readUnsignedShort();
```

Another way to get different numbers out of `byte[]` data is to use `ByteBuffer` since that provides methods like `.getShort()`

```
SerialPort device = SerialPort(file, baud, flags);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(device.getInputStream());
byte[] buffer = new byte[384];
in.readFully(buffer);
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
while (byteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
    int unsigned = byteBuffer.getChar();
    System.out.println(unsigned);
}
```

Comment: Note that DataInputStream assumes big-endian byte ordering and that this cannot be changed.

Comment: That's true. E.g. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/LittleEndianDataInputStream.html would help then. Or the `ByteBuffer` way and specifying the correct `ByteOrder`.